# AWS EC2 Spark Cluster: RSYNC error

Tags: amazon-ec2, apache-spark, rsync

Although the EC2 Management Console shows a running cluster (1 master, 2 slaves), I cannot access the Spark User Interface (UI) on port 8080. During the create & launch command run I got the same RSYNC error as shown in the cluster start command here below.

Can someone explain at least what the RSYNC is trying to do ?. I've read some related posts but people seem to know RSYNC very well and explanations are not obvious at all for ignorants like me :-)

```
ubuntu@eu-west:~/spark-1.5.2/ec2$ ./spark-ec2 --key-pair=westkey --identity-file=/home/ubuntu/westkey.pem --region=eu-west-1 start my-spark-cluster
    Searching for existing cluster my-spark-cluster in region eu-west-1...
    Found 1 master, 2 slaves.
    Starting slaves...
    Starting master...
    Waiting for cluster to enter 'ssh-ready' state..........
    Cluster is now in 'ssh-ready' state. Waited 259 seconds.
    Cloning spark-ec2 scripts from https://github.com/amplab/spark-ec2/tree/branch-1.5 on master...
    Warning: Permanently added 'ec2-54-171-121-28.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com,172.31.16.35' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
    Please login as the user "ubuntu" rather than the user "root".

    Connection to ec2-54-171-121-28.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com closed.
    Deploying files to master...
    Warning: Permanently added 'ec2-54-171-121-28.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com,172.31.16.35' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
    protocol version mismatch -- is your shell clean?
    (see the rsync man page for an explanation)
    rsync error: protocol incompatibility (code 2) at compat.c(174) [sender=3.1.0]
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "./spark_ec2.py", line 1517, in <module>
        main()
      File "./spark_ec2.py", line 1509, in main
        real_main()
      File "./spark_ec2.py", line 1500, in real_main
        setup_cluster(conn, master_nodes, slave_nodes, opts, False)
      File "./spark_ec2.py", line 836, in setup_cluster
        modules=modules
      File "./spark_ec2.py", line 1111, in deploy_files
        subprocess.check_call(command)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 540, in check_call
        raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
    subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['rsync', '-rv', '-e', 'ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -i /home/ubuntu/westkey.pem', '/tmp/tmpJduy3a/', u'root@ec2-54-171-121-28.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com:/']' returned non-zero exit status 2
```

Answer (score 2):

It is trying to execute command

```
rsync -rv -e "ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -i /home/ubuntu/westkey.pem" /tmp/tmpJduy3a/ root@ec2-54-171-121-28.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com:/
```

which means it tries to copy directory tree from `/tmp/tmpJduy3a/` location of your "source" machine to the root filesystem at your destination (ec2-54-171-121-28) machine.
`-rv` options mean that rsync copies directories recursively and outputs verbose information about results.

Up to my wisdom EC2 instance does not allow root user access for ssh, so when I needed to rsync something to EC2 requiring root access access rights I had to add `--rsync-path="sudo rsync"` as an argument of my rsync command.

**PS**: *I cannot make comments for original question now but as long as you are asking about what rsync is trying to do I believe this is qualifying as an answer*

Answer (score 0):

Got the answer: "*spark-ec2 does not support launching clusters running Ubuntu. It's built to work with custom Amazon Linux AMIs that expect you to log in as root and that have specific versions of Unix utilities which may not exist on other distributions.*"[Errors when deploying spark on EC2 with specified AMI-ID](https://github.com/amplab/spark-ec2/issues/27)